# Completing user input in C

Tags: c

I'm learning C so forgive me if this is a rudimentary question...

I have a small program from C Programming Language book that reads user input and attempts to count the number of new lines `'\n'`

When entering input, the enter key adds a new line (which is the intention I believe since we're counting newlines).

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int c, nl;

    nl = 0;
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) 
        if (c == '\n')
            ++nl;
    printf("%1d\n", nl);
}
```

How do I 'finish' the input? I can't seem to hit the printf statement to output the number of newlines.

Comment: You need to give the operating-system specific "end of file" input. For POSIX system (like Linux or macOS) it's `Ctrl-D`. On Windows it's `Ctrl-Z` (which might need to be pressed on a new and empty line).

Comment: ah, that was it, thanks :-)

Answer (score 0):

You should provide End-Of-Transmission character (U+0004) in your output. You can do it this way:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int c, nl;

    nl = 0;
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) 
        if (c == '\n')
            ++nl;
    printf("%1d%c", nl, 4);
}
```

More info about EOT char can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End-of-Transmission_character)